# SQL select order by date in varchar

Tags: mysql, sql

I have my date in database in varchar column and i can't change it. However i want to sort things from newest to latest. My date in database looks like:

```
2014-09-22 10:28:28
```

So what i try is something like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM axnmrs_cases WHERE vin = :vin ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(date_created,'%b-%e-%Y') ASC LIMIT 30";
```

But unfortunately this not change anything for me , even if i change ASC to DESC , nothing changeing in result

and also something like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM axnmrs_cases WHERE vin = :vin ORDER BY CONVERT(date_created, date, 103)";
```

This throw syntax SQL error and I have no idea why.

Is here anybody who can show me the right way?

Answer (score 1):

Date stored in varchar is not a real date and hence the order by also does not give you what you want. The best approach would be store date always in mysql native data types. However in your case you can use `str_to_date()` function to convert the varchar dates to real date and then use it for sort something as

```
order by str_to_date(date_created,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for your answer. However it looks fine it's not working for me. This make no result (no error as well)
`$sql = "SELECT * FROM `axnmrs_cases` WHERE `vin` = ':vin' ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(date_created, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') LIMIT 30";`

Comment: is it change its because i have one SQL in another? .. 
I have something like:
`$stmt->execute();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
ANOTHER SQL IS HERE
}`

Comment: please provide the complete code in the question. Its hard to guess whats going on there but as far as ordering with varchar date is concern the above query should do it.

Comment: Hi, you can find whole code here: http://pastebin.com/1a76XvFM but its  pretty big, idk if it help :(

Comment: Are you sure all the dates in the DB are saved as `Y-m-d H:i:s` format ?

Comment: Yea, I  copy it from database

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `axnmrs_cases` WHERE `vin` = ':vin' ORDER BY `date_created` ASC LIMIT 30";
```

Already tried something like this?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong format in your `STR_TO_DATE` function, if the date is in the format:

```
2014-09-22 10:28:28
```

Then you need to use

```
STR_TO_DATE(date_created, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
```

i.e. the format you give should match the format your varchar is in.

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df7ee/3)**

In your case you are using `'%b-%e-%Y'`, so you are looking for a date like `Jan-1-2014`, for a full list of the specifiers in the format defintion see the [My SQL Docs for DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Also, `CONVERT(date_created, date, 103)` does not work because it is SQL Server Syntax.

Finally, I would really, really try and change the column data type. Storing dates as a varchar is never a good idea. Anything else is just a workaround, not a solution.